# get all values from javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have array like this:

```
a = [{"province":"Western"},{"province":"Central "},{"province":"Southern "}]
```

in javascript. I want to extract all province and put it as in data as mentioned below.

```
data: [{id: 'province1', text: 'province1'},{id: 'province2', text: 'province2'},
       {id: 'province3', text: 'province3'}]
```

I tried it with for loop.

```
for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
    console.log(a[index]);
}
```

But, it's giving me character values..

Comment: you want to go from the first array to the second or... ?

Comment: first array to second. I need all provinces separate..

Comment: I need it like, [{id: 'Western', text: 'Western'}...]

Comment: Seems to work here just fine - http://jsfiddle.net/FkAv7/

Comment: I will just quickly add that a faster for-loop defines the iterating variable, and the length, outside (above) the actual loop. Just something to think about.

Comment: Here's an updated jsFiddle, based on Jay Blanchard's, that I think does what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/FkAv7/1/

Comment: It's working .. but the problem is i am getting the data variable from php by json_encode. it says that text is undefined. the data variable is same ..

Comment: Next time, you may want to include that information in the question. We aren't mind readers.

Comment: I got the answer from @Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = [{"province":"Western"},{"province":"Central "},{"province":"Southern "}], b = {};

for(var i = a.length; i--; b[a[i].province] = a[i].province);

console.log(b);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tL2NT/)

Result is

```
 {Southern : "Southern ", Central : "Central ", Western: "Western"}
```

Edit as per the comment:

```
var a = [{"province":"Western"},{"province":"Central "},{"province":"Southern "}];
a = a.map(function(v){
    return { id : v.province, text : v.province };
});

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Why it's giving me object if I am alerting the variable? In console.log it seems ok

Comment: @user3609998 You cannot alert an object, try alert(JSON.stringify(b))

Comment: we need output in array.. [{Southern : "Southern ", Central : "Central ", Western: "Western"}] (like this)

Comment: @user3609998: `alert` expects a string parameter so your object will be converted to a string, which will be `"[Object object]"` by default. This is one of the reasons you should use console.log instead of alert for debugging.

Comment: actually I need to use variable b like data in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/pHSdP/2/

Comment: perfect .. it's working. 1 more query here. I am getting a variable from php, by means of json_encode. Now the error is like: a.map is not a function. Does it make any difference?

Comment: parse the data you receive from server. Like a = JSON.parse(a)

Comment: :) Glad I was helpful

Answer (score 3):

You can build the ids by concatenating a string with a numeric id:

```
"province" + index // "province1"
```

Summing up

```
var data = [];
for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
    data[index] = { id: 'province' + (index+1), text: a[index].province} ;
}
```